# Custom navigation controller and navigation bar?

Tags: ios

I am well aware of how to implement my own drawing of a navigation bar. What I want to active is something similar to the Jetsetter iPhone application. Which has a very nice animation when swapping between view controllers (in a similar way you would push/pop view controllers in a UINavigationController stack).

Would this require a complete rewrite of the UINavigationController or could I somehow just override some vital parts?

I would be great full for any information right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, they hide the navigation bar and roll their own view.
 
Please check this [link](http://eddev.tumblr.com/post/27771453668/hide-navigation-bar-and-programatically-call-back).

Answer (score 0):

On some views they are not using a navigation bar, they are just creating a simple view and adding buttons for popping and pushing, but on some views, they change the navigation bar background and initialize the backbarbutton and forward button items and title with their own views and then add gestures recognizers to these, its very simple.